# How does pip organizes packages when "pip freeze > requirements.txt"?

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

Whenever I run the command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The packages are ordered in a random way because they are not Alphabetically ordered neither by the package version. Example:

```
Twisted >= 17.9.0
lxml>=3.2.4
pyOpenSSL>=0.13.1
cssselect>=0.9
queuelib>=1.1.1
w3lib>=1.17.0
```

So, what is used then? Is it just random?

Comment: You must have an old or broken version of `pip`. Since at least version 7, `pip` lists and freezes [packages in a case-insensitive sorted order](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py#L18).

Comment: [And here is the code line responsible for the case-insensitive sorting.](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py#L153)